# White Space on the right in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help finding what exactly is causing the white space on the right in mobile view of my site. 
http://shahil229-001-site1.smarterasp.net/

I've tried using overflow-x : hidden in the css but it stops the top navbar animations from working in the normal desktop view so thats out of the question.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue! In the box where it says "SYSPRO" your link seems to be overflowing. Therefore causing it to make the page wider then it should be, and you can't see it because the link is white.

**EDIT**

Specifically the link `http://www.syspro.com/product/what-is-erp`.

**EDIT 2**

As Jesse Dockett said, also add `width: 100%` to your code. Thank You Jesse! :)

Comment: To add to Michael's answer. To prevent this issue from happening again (your text will still go off of the screen) add "width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;" to the CSS for body. Missing the "width: 100%; is what prevented you from locking that width in before.

Comment: Thank you so so so much!...Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Yep @user2806570, no problem :)